# How do i prove if this is true or false?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Is $\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)=\mathcal{P}(A)\cup\mathcal{P}(B)$ true for all sets $A$ and $B$?  If so, prove it.  If not, give an example of sets $A$ and $B$ for which it is false and show why it is false for these sets.

Comment: What have you tried?  $A$ and $B$ can be rather small, so trying some small cases should suffice.

Comment: yea i got it now cause i used a smaller set. was using quite large sets before and it was really tedious

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. Does $2^{a+b}=2^a+2^b-1$ for integers $a,b \ge 0$ ?

Comment: where does the -1 come from?

Comment: @ε-δ Even if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and $\mathcal{P}(B)$ have one element in common ...

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks!